# How to merge multiple csv files on common columns and keep the non common ones as separate columns?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have three `csv` files which contains data about covid 19. The first `csv` has information about number of `confirmed cases`, the second one has information about `number of deaths` and the third one has information about `number of recovery`.

So this is how the dataframes looks like

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('/Users/sr/covid_csvs/confirmed.csv')

df2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/sr/covid_csvs/deaths.csv')

df3 = pd.read_csv('/Users/sr/covid_csvs/recovery.csv')

print(df1.head(5))

  Province/State Country/Region      Lat     Long     Date  Confirmed
0            NaN    Afghanistan  33.0000  65.0000  1/22/20          0
1            NaN        Albania  41.1533  20.1683  1/22/20          0
2            NaN        Algeria  28.0339   1.6596  1/22/20          0
3            NaN        Andorra  42.5063   1.5218  1/22/20          0
4            NaN         Angola -11.2027  17.8739  1/22/20          0


print(df2.head(5))

  Province/State Country/Region      Lat     Long     Date     Deaths
0            NaN    Afghanistan  33.0000  65.0000  1/22/20          0
1            NaN        Albania  41.1533  20.1683  1/22/20          0
2            NaN        Algeria  28.0339   1.6596  1/22/20          0
3            NaN        Andorra  42.5063   1.5218  1/22/20          0
4            NaN         Angola -11.2027  17.8739  1/22/20          0


print(df3.head(5))

  Province/State Country/Region      Lat     Long     Date  Recovery
0            NaN    Afghanistan  33.0000  65.0000  1/22/20         0
1            NaN        Albania  41.1533  20.1683  1/22/20         0
2            NaN        Algeria  28.0339   1.6596  1/22/20         0
3            NaN        Andorra  42.5063   1.5218  1/22/20         0
4            NaN         Angola -11.2027  17.8739  1/22/20         0
```

Now I want to merge all the three dataframes such that I get the below result

```
  Province/State Country/Region      Lat     Long     Date  Confirmed  Deaths Recovery
0            NaN    Afghanistan  33.0000  65.0000  1/22/20          0       0        0
1            NaN        Albania  41.1533  20.1683  1/22/20          0       0        0
2            NaN        Algeria  28.0339   1.6596  1/22/20          0       0        0
3            NaN        Andorra  42.5063   1.5218  1/22/20          0       0        0
4            NaN         Angola -11.2027  17.8739  1/22/20          0       0        0
```

So I tried doing something like below

```
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])    
df_merged.to_csv('merged.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

But I do not get the required `csv`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for each `DataFrame`, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1` and last remove `index=False` in `to_csv`:

```
cols = ['Province/State', 'Country/Region','Lat','Long','Date']

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df_merged = pd.concat([x.set_index(cols) for x in dfs], axis=1)    
df_merged.to_csv('merged.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Or convert `MultiIndex` to column and then use `index=False` in `to_csv`:

```
cols = ['Province/State', 'Country/Region','Lat','Long','Date']

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df_merged = pd.concat([x.set_index(cols) for x in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()  
df_merged.to_csv('merged.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```