# Merge Different Column Using Python

Tags: python, merge

I would like to combine hundreds of time series csv file and all of them look like this:

| time | filename1 |
| --- | --- |
| t1 | value1 |
| t2 | value2 |

I would like to combine all the csv into one excel for presentation. What I want is something like this:

| time | filename1 | filename2 | ...filename n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | value | value | value |
| t2 | value | value | value |

I tried merge/join but i cannot get what I want

```
Time_col=[] 
TS_col=[]
TimeSeries=[]
df_combine = pd.DataFrame
for n in filename:
 TS = pd.read_csv(folderpath+fileTS, usecols=[1]).to_numpy()
 Time = pd.read_csv(folderpath+fileTS, usecols=[0]).to_numpy()  
 for i in range(0,len(TS)):
     TS_col.append(TS[i][0])
     Time_col.append(Time[i][0]) 
 TimeSeries = {'time':Time_col, filename[n]:TS_col} 
 df = pd.DataFrame(TimeSeries) 
 df_combine = df.merge(df, on='time')
```

Please help....
Thank you very much

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138367/how-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-on-common-columns-and-keep-the-non-common-ones-a